# MouseLeave behaving like MouseOut?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseleave, mouseout

I feel like I'm going insane... So, as per my understanding and seemingly the universal consensus of the internet, `mouseout` fires on the cursor leaving an element or any of it's children, whilst `mouseleave` only fires on the cursor leaving the element the event is attached to. So I take something as barebones as this:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id='test'>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script>
    const div = document.getElementById('test');
    div.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => console.log('out'), true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

... and the `mouseleave` event is definitely still firing when the mouse leaves any of the descendents of that div. I feel like I must be doing something so obviously wrong, but... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove last argument from your `addEventListener` - it is called `useCapture` and by default its `false`. If you pass `true`, when event will be fired on capturing phase, which will cause firing `mouseleave` on every child element. Read more about `useCapture` parameter - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

`mouseleave` event doesn't bubbles because of that it will not trigger parent event when leaving child element. But when you pass `useCapture` - you force event to be fired on capturing phase. Event phases on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/eventPhase

```js
const div = document.getElementById('test');
div.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => console.log('out')); // Remove `true`
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id='test'>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```